# Letsencrypt cert cannot be updated with nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I've updated certificate for nginx, but in Firefox browser is still use the old one. I've check new certificate and it says

> cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
>
> openssl x509 -in $cert_file -text -noout
>
> Not After : Oct  5 21:50:00 2016 GMT

Nginx settings:

> ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
>
> ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/chain.pem;
>
> ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

But in browser I still see the old certificate. I've restarted nginx but still the same situation, It's pretty weird.

Then I COMPLETELY removed all certs and generate a new one. It's still the same...

In what cache old certs still present?

Anyone can help me?

Comment: have you cleaned your firefox browser cache of certifications?

Comment: While browsers should not ideally "cache" certificates they can utalise a protocol to *resume* a previously certified session with the server, rather than spending CPU (on both ends) negotiating a new session for every visit.